# Let $a\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Is there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $C_{00}$ such that $\|a_n\|_{\ell^1}<K$ and $\|a_n-a\|_{\ell_2}\to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Problem: Let $a\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Is there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $C_{00}$ such that $\|a_n\|_{\ell^1}$ is uniformly bounded and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\|a_n-a\|_{\ell_2}= 0$?

My Opinion: It is clear that there always exists a sequence $(b_n)\in C_{00}$ such that $\|b_n-a\|_{\ell^2}\to 0$, and $\|b_n\|_{\ell^2}$ is uniformly bounded. But it is not clear for me that whether we can choose a a sequence $(a_n)\in C_{00}$ such that $\|a_n-a\|_{\ell^2}\to 0$, and $\|a_n\|_{\ell^1}$ is uniformly bounded. I also try to contradict this fact, but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is not true, unless the sequence $a$ belongs to $\ell^1.$ Let $a_n\in C_{00},$  $\|a_n-a\|_2\to 0$ and $\|a_n\|_1\le C.$  Then $a_n(k)\to a(k)$ for any $k.$ Therefore for any fixed $K$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^K|a(k)|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^K|a_n(k)|\le C$$
As $K$ is arbitrary we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a(k)|\le C$$
i.e. $a\in \ell^1.$